# Как сделать конфигурации debug и release одинаковыми?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, silverlight

У меня есть проект A, написанный под .net FrameWork 4.0. В нём используется метод Load из одной библиотеки. Эта библиотека собрана из другого проекта B, написанного под Silverlight 5. И во время отладки, при вызове этого метода Load, у меня возникает ошибка:

Unexpected error: Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "System.Xml, Version=5.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e" либо одну из их зависимостей. Не удается найти указанный файл.,    в )

При этом всём, в релизной сборке проекта A такой ошибки не возникает и всё работает корректно.

Можете объяснить из-за чего это происходит и как мне сделать конфигурации debug и release одинаковыми, чтобы и при отладке ошибки не было?

Comment: Судя по ошибке и поведению - у вас в библиотеке ```Б``` нет отладочной информации, отсюда и ошибка при отладке ```А```

Comment: Но проект Б при своей отладке использует System.Xml.dll из Silverlight 5. Соответственно, именно эта отладочная информация попадёт в библиотеку Б. И тогда, при отладке А, всё равно будет ошибка.

Comment: Зачем вам давно мёртвый Silvrlight? Под Windows XP софт чтоли пишете? Есть же WPF и куча других актуальных UI движков.

Comment: Я бы с радостью использовал, что-то поновее и поудобнее, но, увы, в данной ситуации решаю не я. Я работаю с тем, что мне дали.

Comment: @Zhizhka можете воспользоваться хитростью, сказать следующее: "это нельзя поддерживать, необходимо переписывать")

Comment: Какая версия .net в сборке которую нельзя подключить?

Comment: @Kalmankantaja 4.0

Comment: К ней доступ есть? Посмотрите её зависимости, может надо попробовать понизить версию пакетов до 4

Comment: @Kalmankantaja доступ есть, но понизить версии пакетов не получится, иначе другое приложение, из которого и взята библиотека Б не будет работать.

Comment: И как же оно раньше работало? Или не работало?

Comment: Оно и сейчас работает, но только в релизной сборке. А вот в отладке возникает ошибка. И я собственно и пытаюсь понять почему в релизе оно работает, а в дебаге нет

Comment: Я думаю, под Release оно работает потому, что у вас по нужному пути подложена правильная версия System.Xml.dll, а под Debug ее нет. Либо у вас app.config разные, и в одному из них прописан Binding redirect, а в другом нет. Алгоритм разрешения сборок в Debug и Release не отличается, отличаются только пути.

Comment: Так или иначе, идея использовать код под Silverlight в .NET Framework довольно сомнительная. Эта проблема должна, по идее, решаться созданием Portable class library определенного профиля, который поддерживает и Silverlight и .NET Framework.